# Spring - Issue configuring Hibernate Jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm moving from a Spring Boot 1.5.9 to a normal Spring project.

In `application.properties` I've added

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[0]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[1]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[2]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[3]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

I have a configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateJpaConfig {

private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();

public HibernateJpaConfig() {
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa"); dataSource.setPassword("");
    return dataSource;
}

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired(required = false)
private PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager;

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    AbstractJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setShowSql(false);
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("H2");
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder(JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder = new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(
            jpaVendorAdapter, properties,
            this.persistenceUnitManager);
    builder.setCallback(null);
    return builder;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder factoryBuilder) {
    Map<String, Object> vendorProperties = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    vendorProperties.putAll(properties);

    return factoryBuilder.dataSource(this.dataSource).packages("com.fabio.springmvc.domain")
            .properties(vendorProperties).jta(false).build();
}

}
```

When I run the project I have the following errors (I've added a warning since it seems pertinent to the issue)

```
    2018-01-07 06:03:34.542  WARN 17268 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/fabio/springmvc/config/HibernateJpaConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2018-01-07 06:03:34.545  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-01-07 06:03:34.557  INFO 17268 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-01-07 06:03:34.564 ERROR 17268 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/fabio/springmvc/config/HibernateJpaConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at com.fabio.springmvc.SpringmvcApplication.main(SpringmvcApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.fabio.springmvc.domain.Customer column: addressLine1 (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:830) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:848) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:844) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:870) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:605) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
... 28 common frames omitted
```

The configuration class is based on a course with Spring boot 1.3, here I'm using 1.5.9, I don't get why I'm having this issue.

Edit for customer repeated column

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends AbstractDomainClass{

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String phoneNumber;
@Embedded
private Address billingAddress;
@Embedded
private Address shippingAddress;
// getters setters
}
```

Address class

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {

private String addressLine1;
private String addressLine2;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zipCode;
// getters setters
}
```

Comment: Did you see this `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.fabio.springmvc.domain.Customer column: addressLine1 (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
`?

Comment: I missed it, regardless customer.addressLine1 comes from an embedded class, I've edited both in for clarity. I'm having no such issue if I use the auto configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs because you have the following mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends AbstractDomainClass {
    //other attributes...
    @Embedded
    private Address billingAddress;
    @Embedded
    private Address shippingAddress;
}
```

Here, what Hibernate will try to do is to map the attributes of the `@Embedded` class in columns of your table. This is, it will map `Address#addressLine1` from attribute `Address billingAddress` to the column `addressLine1` in the table `customer`. Similar will happen with the other fields for attribute `billingAddress` and for class `Address`. And then, it will do the same with `Address shippingAddress`, this is, it will map `Address#addressLine1` for `shippingAddress` to column `addressLine1` in table `customer`. This is the cause of the exception.

Since this is more a design problem rather than an issue in your code, I would suggest some ways to solve it.

1. Have different columns in your table for all the fields, and map each one to the specific attribute in classes. Here's a basic example:

   DDL of your table (using the most common sql I can come up with).

   ```
   CREATE TABLE customer (
       id INT NOT NULL,
       billingAddressLine1 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
       shippingAddressLine1 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
       -- other columns...
       PRIMARY KEY(id)
   );
   ```

   Hibernate mapping for `@Embedded` attributes using `@AttributeOverrides`:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Customer extends AbstractDomainClass {
       //other attributes...
       @Embedded
       @AttributeOverrides(
           @AttributeOverride(
               name = "addressLine1",
               column = @Column(name = "billingAddressLine1"),
           )
           //do similar for the other attributes...
       )
       private Address billingAddress;
       @Embedded
       @AttributeOverrides(
           @AttributeOverride(
               name = "addressLine1",
               column = @Column(name = "shippingAddressLine1")
           )
           //do similar for the other attributes...
       )
       private Address shippingAddress;
   }
   ```
2. Instead of having the columns in the `customer` table, use a separate table called `address` and a column called `addressType` (or the name you prefer) to store addresses for a customer.

   DDL of your table (using the most common sql I can come up with).

   ```
   CREATE TABLE customer (
       id INT NOT NULL,
       -- other columns...
       PRIMARY KEY(id)
   );

   CREATE TABLE address (
       id INT NOT NULL,
       addressType INT NOT NULL,
       customer_id INT NOT NULL,
       addressLine1 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
       -- other columns...
       PRIMARY KEY(id),
       FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(id)
   );
   ```

   Hibernate mapping for the classes (not `@Embedded`):

   ```
   //@Embedded
   @Entity
   public class Address extends AbstractDomainClass {

       private String addressLine1;
       private String addressLine2;
       private String city;
       private String state;
       private String zipCode;

       //new fields...
       private int addressType;
       @ManyToOne
       private Customer customer;
       // getters and setters ...
   }

   @Entity
   public class Customer extends AbstractDomainClass {
       //other attributes...
       @OneToOne(mappedBy="customer", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
       private Address billingAddress;
       @OneToOne(mappedBy="customer", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
       private Address shippingAddress;
       //getters and setters...
   }
   ```

Comment: I've used the first solution and that fixed it. But why is it that it configures properly when i use spring boot autoconfiguration while it has issues when i use a configuration class ? I would much more prefer having to tweak my configuration that the entities.